# discord.js Bot V12 Want to make a type of weekly, day hour clock

Tags: discord.js

The thing I want to do is to send message each Monday at 10:00 AM.
Here is the my code where I was using cron, and this is a Thursday example which isn't working

```
const cron = require('cron');

let scheduledMessage = new cron.CronJob('00 23 12 * * 4', () => {

  client.channels.cache.get("821610650403864596").send("Hello World!");
});
scheduledMessage.start()
```

Comment: "but it dont works" is not going to help us. Please include debugging details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you use cron to send a message at schedule, you can change syntax via the cron docs

```js
//declare packages here
const cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('00 23 12 * * 4', function() {
   console.log('sending');
   client.channels.cache.get("821610650403864596").send("Hello World!");
}, {
    scheduled: true,
    timezone: "America/New_York" //change to your need
});

client.login(config.token); //login (if no config.json file replace with your token)
```

this is how to structure a cron job - try using the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) next time though.